# What does this statement have to do with continuity of metric?

Tags: real-analysis

For a metric space $X$, a point $x \in X$ and $r_1 < r_2$, we have $B(x,r_1)\subseteq B(x,r_2)$.
From the continuity of the metric, we infer that closure of $B(x, r_1)$ is closed and contains $B(x, r_1)$. The closure of $B(x, r_1)$ is contained in $B(x, r_2)$

The statement seems to be universally correct to me. Can anyone explain its connection with metric space and continuity of metric?

Comment: $d:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. It follows that $d(x,\cdot)$ is continuous. What is $d(x,\cdot)^{-1}\big((-\infty,r_1]\big)$?

Comment: What definition of closure are you working with?